# Creating Dynamic Hotspots in an ASP.net imagemap

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, imagemap

I need the ability to create a dynamic number of hotspots in an imagemap
the pseudo code for what I want to do is below:

```
Protected Sub AddHotSpot()
    Dim r1 New RectangleHotSpot
For Each Item as datarow in dataset
        r1.HotSpotMode = HotSpotMode.PostBack
        r1.PostBackValue = "HotSpot 1"
        r1.AlternateText = "HotSpot 1"

        r1.Top = Item.Top
        r1.Left = Item.Left
        r1.Bottom = Item.Bottom
        r1.Right = Item.Right
Next
```

think of r1 as some form of dynamic construct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to perform this. I had to make the object above part of an array list then add each object to the array